# Vue.js TypeError: Message Cannot read property 'singlePost' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have blog in vue.js
I want to preview each post separately. 
I do this>

```
export default{
  name: 'post',
  props:['id'],
  data(){
    return {
      singlePost: { }
    }
  },
  created() {
    BlogPostsApi.getPost(this.id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.singlePost = response.data
      })
  }
```

in blogPosts.js i have this code>

```
import axios from'axios';
export default{
  getPost (id) {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/posts/ddc/' + id)
      .then(response => {
        debugger
        return response.data
      })
  }
}
```

When i'm debugging i get this error Message Cannot read property 'singlePost' of undefined

Comment: Can't see anywhere in your code where you actually attempt to **read** `singlePost`. Which line of your code does the error point to?

Comment: i get this error when i'm debugging actually in created() in line this.singlePost = response.data

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"when I'm debugging"_? Is the error coming from your code or from something you're typing into the console?

Comment: I have debugger in my code .then(response => {
        debugger
        return response.data
      })
and i go line by line

Answer (score -1):

```
 created() {
var self = this
    BlogPostsApi.getPost(this.id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        self.singlePost = response.data
      })
  }
```

The problem is solved